# Google Cloud functions 2nd gen run twice

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I've started using 2nd gen google cloud functions recently, and I have this issue that they run twice. Same code as with gen 1.
It goes to the end of the function, and just starts the code again.

Say my entry point is called hello_world.
Simplest code in the world:

```
def hello_world(request):

  print('start')


  print('Stop')

  return 'Hello World!'
```

Yet it just runs it twice. Seems [See example - code run twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ton72.png)

Must be missing something incredibly obvious..
I run this one with a HTTP trigger, basic, no auth. Just launched it once.
Edit: I tested a larger function that has the same issue:

- With postman, it only triggered once
- in private mode on the browser, it only triggered once
- normal browser, triggered twice
- cloud scheduler, triggered 3 times!!

Comment: How this Cloud Function is triggered please ?

Comment: Sorry delete my comment by mistake - new here. Triggered via HTTP Get. The issue does not occur with Postman or running it in incognito mode. Unfortunately still happens with cloud scheduler on some of my 2nd gen functions

Answer (score 0):

Using a browser for this kind of test isn't recommended because browsers do all sorts of things behind the scenes when making requests. For example, if your function is configured to respond to any path (e.g., it will respond to `/` and `/foo` and `/bar` and anything else) then you're likely going to see this behavior due to the browser attempting to load `favicon.ico`. You can test this with the following steps, assuming that you're using Chrome:

1. Open your browser in **a new private window**
2. Open the *Developer Tools* from the View menu > Developer > Developer Tools
3. Click the *Network* tab
4. Check *Disable Cache*
5. Paste in your function URL in the address bar and press Enter

In the log below you may see only one request. If so click and hold on the Refresh button in the browser until you see *Empty cache and hard reload*, then click that and observe the Network tab again. You should see both a request for the original URL *and* for `favicon.ico`. If your function is configured to respond to any path then that will trigger your function twice.

Additionally, depending on how your request is made it may trigger a [CORS preflight OPTIONS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) which likewise may trigger your function's business logic depending on how it is written.

Since your post doesn't include the function's configuration it's hard to say if either of these are occurring.

Given that browsers can introduce unexpected additional requests you should test your function using a tool specifically designed for it like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) or [RapidAPI](https://rapidapi.com/). These tools will make specific and singular requests that you can use to confirm the behavior.

Alternatively, as a simpler test of the problem you can use [`curl`](https://curl.se/):

```bash
curl -i "https://<your-unique-url>.run.app/"
```

This should return only a single result in Cloud Logging, the same as it should for any of the above mentioned tools besides the browser.

You can find that single result if you observe the output which will include a header named `x-cloud-trace-context` with a 32 character hexadecimal value followed by a semicolon and some additional value. You can use Cloud Logging to search for that specific request. For example, if the value is `d04711e17a0682213f96f6d851289e1e;o=1` then you can visit the following URL to search for that request:

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/query;query="d04711e17a0682213f96f6d851289e1e"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I understand therefore that the behavior is browser induced and not necessarily in the code. 
I tested with my larger function and when launched in private mode, it did not run twice. When run via cloud scheduler it run 3 times (!!). Is there any specific setting I should look out for ? I honestly did not update default values.
Very much a beginner :)